# Integrating Timescape into Tableau

Tags: database-connection

I'm trying to integrate [Timescape](http://www.xenomorph.com/timescape-edm/) to [Tableau](http://www.tableau.com/).

Does anyone know the connection object / connection string I need to use in Tableau to access my Timescape environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While timescape suggests [there is an integration](http://www.xenomorph.com/xenomorph-timescape-edm-integrates-tableau-visualizations-2/) of timescape and tableau, I had hoped the integration was a live connection.

Having contacted [Timescape](http://www.xenomorph.com/timescape-edm/) support, who were quick to respond, they explained that the integration is by way of exporting to a TDE file. Any fresh update of data needs a new TDE file generated.

So there is no connection string to connect directly to a timescape instance.